# What are some Russian shibboleths?

Tags: выражения, история-языка

I just read about [shibboleths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth) and I was wondering: what are some Russian shibboleths used today or in the past?

A shibboleth is a phrase (or a custom/tradition) that is used to distinguish between groups of people, often depending on whether or not the speaker can properly pronounce the phrase.

Here is a list of examples: [List of shibboleths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_shibboleths)

Comment: it's more of historical interest rather than a linguistics one - the knowledge of shibboleth doesn't contribute in learning Russian.
Also your question by it's nature can not have a single accepted answer.

Comment: "Запомните, дети тарелька и вилька пишется без мягкого знака, а сол и фасол с мягким знаком запомните это дети, ибо понять этого не возможно!!!"

Comment: Just try to say 'Ы' :)

Comment: The name of the city of Odessa is pronounced by the locals with a soft d.

Comment: Пермь has a soft **р** when said by a local.

Comment: @Sergey Slepov - I can understand "Одэсса", but do outsiders actually say "Пэрмь"?

Comment: @Alexander, no, outsiders say Пермь while insiders say Перьмь.

Comment: @Sergey Slepov oh, sorry, that was Russian "р" (not English "p") in your message.

Comment: Перьмь is not a shibbolleth, whether regional or general - any speaker who can pronounce Пермь can pronounce Перьмь as well - shibbolletsh are more about phrase that non-native speaker can not correctly pronounce at all.

Comment: @shabunc do we have a separate site for advanced Russian language usage? The question could be moved there I think...

Comment: @Alissa imagine a question - which phrase Russian conspirators who killed emperor Pavel used as a password? Is it about Russian language? Nope, it's about history. 

A question about phrase that was used to tell apart non-native Russian speakers from native ones is a historical as well. This is not a question about Russian language, advanced or not. 

Honestly, I'd rather ask at history.